# std tag for gfortran will output Wtabs warnings come what may

Tags: tabs, fortran, compiler-warnings, gfortran

when compiling my code with these variants:

```
gfortran -Wno-tabs --std=f2018 brains.f95 -o brains
gfortran -Wtabs --std=f2018 brains.f95 -o brains
gfortran --std=f2018 -Wno-tabs brains.f95 -o brains
gfortran --std=f2018 -Wtabs brains.f95 -o brains
```

I get several Wtab warnings from the compiler for my tab spaces in the code. I compile without the std tag and I don't have this problem. The code compiles without incident. Surely there is some way to use the std tag and suppress all the tab warnings in gfortran at the same time, but there is no advice anywhere in internet-land that achieves this gargantuan feat.

Comment: You request strict standard conformance and wish to use a non-standard conforming source code form. I am afraid it might be impossible, i.e. it is quite possible that `--std=f2018` overrides `-Wno-tabs`. It is just a warning anyway. You can easilly fix your code instead.

Comment: The gfortran [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Error-and-Warning-Options.html#Error-and-Warning-Options) even explicitly says `-Wtabs is active for -pedantic, -std=f95, -std=f2003, -std=f2008, -std=f2018 and -Wall.`

Comment: This is true @VladimirF, I do indeed aggree that this is not a particularly troublesome issue. It would seem to me, though, that it should be possible to suppress a single  innocuous warning type and also retain the rest of the standard.

Comment: I can say with some certainty that gfortran will never have an option to suppress the -Wtabs warning when -std=f95 etc is used.  Why?  Because I'm the person that introduced -Wtabs to gfortran.  When this option was introduce there was a very long email thread spanning a month or so with various people providing input (hint: gfortran has a mailing list archive).  tabs are an abomination, which should be removed from all keyboards.